# Determine the distributionof $Y=u(x)$ given the distribution of $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here are some notes taken for probability:
If we know the distribution of X, here are ways to determine the distribution of $Y=u(x).

If X is discrete, then Y=u(x) is always discrete, and  $P_Y(y)=P(Y=y)=P(u(X)=y)=\sum_{x:u(x)=y} P_{x}(x)$

First question: What's the general idea in comprehending this?

Another special case for X being discrete is if u(x) is one-to-one on $S_X$, then $P_Y(y)=P_X(u^{-1}(y))$.

Second question: How to comprehend this one? And how do people come up with that?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between $\large{P_x(x)}$ and $\large{P_X(x})$? Clearly $P_Y(y)=P(Y=y)$, so $P_X(x)=P(X=x)$. But $P_x(x)$ doesn't seem meaningful...

Comment: In any case,$$\sum_{x\,:\,u(x)=y}P_X(x)$$reads "the sum of all probabilities $P(X=x)$ where $x$ satisfies $y=u(x)$". For example, if $u(x)=x^2$, then $P(Y=1)=P(X=1)+P(X=-1)$.